# ajax запрос работает в FF но даёт ошибку 400 в Chromium и IE. В чём проблема?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Здравствуйте
Есть запрос:

```
function call_via_ajax(pagelink) {

    var data = {
        action: 'call_ajax_content',
        pagelink: pagelink
    };

    jQuery.post( "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
        // change content
        jQuery("#primary").html(response);

        // change URL string
        history.pushState({}, null, pagelink);

    });
}
```

php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_ajax_content', 'call_ajax_content_callback');
function call_ajax_content_callback() {
    $pagelink =  $_POST['pagelink'];
    pattern = "/<main[^>]*>(.*?)<\/main>/is";

    preg_match($pattern, file_get_contents($pagelink), $matches);

    echo($matches[1]);
    wp_die();
```

}

всё прекрасно работает в Firefox но даёт ошибку 400 в chrome и IE.

jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST http://192.168.1.233/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
Что нужно изменить?

Comment: Обычно, такая ошибка вылезает когда вы не шлете на сервер данных, которые он ожидает получить. Не уверен, что проблема именно с этим, но сталкивался с подобным: постройте обычный `ajax` запрос, не используйте `jQuery.post`. Есть ещё вероятность того, что при вызове в `js` вашей функции, переменная `pagelink` равна пустой строке, в таком случае она может даже не отправляться на сервер.

Comment: с pagelink всё в порядке. у неё значение - существующий URL. Почему сервер не понимает запросы именно от chrome и IE, но прекрасно понимает Firefox? В чём разница в работе браузеров?

Comment: firefox: action call_ajax_content
pagelink http://192.168.1.233/index.php/page/2/  chrome: action:call_ajax_content
pagelink:http://192.168.1.233/index.php/page/2/

Comment: запросы по ходу одинаковые. кстати перестроил запрос без jQuery.post - результат тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Протестировал я ваш код в отладчике, пошагово. Запрос проходит на сервер, вызывается файл `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Его выполнение завершается на строке 169 (у вас, может, другая - у меня на тестовом сервере WordPress 5.0 Alpha)

```
if ( ! has_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}" ) ) {
    wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

Так происходит, потому что у вас не зарегистрирована акция `wp_ajax_nopriv_call_ajax_content`. В вашем коде на сервере должна быть не одна строчка, а две:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_ajax_content', 'call_ajax_content_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_ajax_content', 'call_ajax_content_callback');
```

Первая акция срабатывает, если пользователь не залогинен, а вторая - если залогинен.

Поэтому резюме: браузеры ни при чём. Вы в FF залогинены, а в остальных - нет. Потому в остальных браузерах вам WP возвращает 400.

Comment: Спасибо. Полезный ответ поставил

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.